# Yii2 & PostreSQL: How to change column type from string to jsonb?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

In table I have a column "language", which is type of string and stores values like: "en", "ru", etc. Now I need to store multiple values, for example: ["en", "ru"]. So, I decided to create new column "languageb" with type jsonb and delete "language" column. Important thing is that the current value of "language" column must be saved to "languageb" column. I mean, if the value of column "language" is "en", then the value of column "languageb" must be saved as ["en"]. 
So, I try to create new migration:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE ".$this->tableName." SET languageb = language")->execute();
```

The error is:

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column "languageb" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the column language to be render as a jsonb before affecting it.

Try something like that :

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE ".$this->tableName." SET languageb = language::jsonb[]")->execute();
```

See the postgres documentation for more info for casting : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html

Comment: Exception: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "ru" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ru

Comment: Array of JSONB values does not strike me as a good design in this case. I would either go with JSONB array (this is not the same) or text array. That error reported by OP means that you can't just cast any text value to JSON or array (JSON or otherwise).